# Angular Service not hitting API endpoint

Tags: angular

I'm trying to test out a service called vpnblocker, which will detect if user is using a VPN or not. I'm following the [documentation](https://vpnblocker.net/usage/api-parameters/) and [API variables](https://vpnblocker.net/usage/api-variables/) and I've set up my angular service to call API, but it never returns any values. Nothing outputs between the console.logs in ngOnInit. Why is that?

angular component

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("VPN IS RUNNING FUNCTION START");
    this.loginService.vpnIsRunning().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
    console.log("VPN IS RUNNING FUNCTION END");

  }
```

angular service

```
    vpnIsRunning() {
    let format = "json";
    let ip = "45.87.214.236";
    return this.http
      .get<{
        posts: any;
      }>(`http://api.vpnblocker.net/v2/${format}/${ip}`)
      .pipe(
        map(retrievedData => {
          return {
            posts: retrievedData.posts.map(post => {
              return {
                status: post.status,
                ipaddress: post.ipaddress,
                msg: post.msg
              };
            })
          };
        })
      );
  }
```

console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.vpnblocker.net/v2/json/72.238.50.117' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
login.component.ts:60 HTTP Error HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://api.vpnblocker.net/v2/json/72.238.50.117", ok: false, …}
zone-evergreen.js:2952 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://api.vpnblocker.net/v2/json/72.238.50.117 with MIME type text/javascript. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Comment: Nothing would post between the two console.logs in ngOnInit sync the command executes asynchronously.   Is the output of the console.log occurring after or not at all?  Also can you see if the network call is actually executing in your developer tools?

Comment: Looks like its somehow related to cors? I thought cors was only configured on server side though? the console.logs appear on page load with nothing in between.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should catch the http get. as you have an httpError.

Example:

```
.subscribe(
    res => console.log('HTTP response', res),
    err => console.log('HTTP Error', err),
    () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
);
```

**UPDATE**

https://vpnblocker.net/usage/http-status-codes/

`Forbidden – This occurs when you try requesting from the API server using SSL (HTTPS) without the Basic or Professional package.`

If you are testing on http or localhost you will get this error.

use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to serve your localhost on https.

Comment: I looked at the angular http header documentation, but I'm still getting the same error after adding headers to api call. https://pastebin.com/dq9yhFnZ Do you know why that is? I added console output above

Comment: Does that mean the issue would go away when I deploy to aws s3 to host my angular app?

Comment: you can test locally by forwarding your `http:localhost` to `https:ngrok.....`. see the docs on ngrok. but yea it will probably work on https.

Answer (score 0):

To make cross origin requests you need to use the HttpClientJsonpModule and the jsonp method of the service.

More into here https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-jsonp-request